# CMD Batch - Find literal string

Tags: batch-file, cmd, find

Got an interesting problem. I'm pulling a query on a registry to see if it exists - if it does, I go down one path. If it doesn't, I go down a seperate path. I'll put a code example at the bottom. Here's the question:

FIND doesn't have an /L switch I can use for literal interpretation. One of my settings is 4, and the other is 14. So 14 works great, 4 finds both 4 and 14.

Is there a way to have it find "4" rather than just 4? Using escape characters before the quotations or double quoting just makes it miss entirely.

This is just an example of what I mean. Names and values changed to protect the innocent. This is part of a much larger script, so 'enabledelayedexpansion' is necessary.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set ValueOne=4
set ValueTwo=14

    rem This section determines if additional specific concept settings are needed.
:ConceptCheck
rem DEBUG
echo CONCEPT CHECK

for /f "tokens=1" %%G in ('reg query hklm\software\SomeRegistry\ /v "Value" ^| find "!ValueTwo!"') do (
echo Value Two Found!
call :ValueTwoSetup)

for /f "tokens=1" %%G in ('reg query hklm\software\SomeRegistry\ /v "Value" ^| find "!ValueOne!"') do (
echo Value One Found!
call :ValueOneSetup)

goto :eof
```

When run, if the entry is ValueTwo, it works great. ValueOne calls both ValueTwo and itself, due to the fact that 14 has the number 4 in it, and find catches it. I've tried ""!ValueOne!"", but then it fails utterly. I've tried "^"!ValueOne!^"" to the same result. I CAN stick an 'goto :eof' at the end of the do call, but then I lose expandability, and I still have to monitor which value shows up first, which makes things more complicated and clumsy. I'll be dealing with around two hundred 'values' by the time I'm done, and they aren't sequential.

Thoughts?

Comment: Disregard, figured out it out myself. I'll look for REG_SZ 4 instead.

Answer (score 0):

[findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) has `\<` and `\>` special characters to indicate word boundaries:

```
findstr /r /c:"\<!ValueOne!\>"
```

Alternatively you can instruct `reg query` to use exact match by adding `/e`, so no need for `find`:

```
reg query hklm\software\SomeRegistry /s /v "Value" /d /e /f "!ValueOne!" >nul
if not errorlevel 1 echo ValueOne Found! & call :ValueOneSetup
```

Comment: Can't use FindStr. You can't pipe a command into it, it only reads from files - otherwise, I'd use the /L for a literal interpretation. However, didn't think about /e with reg query. Good call. In my solution that I thought of just a few minutes ago, I searched for "REG_SZ    !ValueOne!" which works fine. Don't know why I didn't think of it first before I started fiddling around with switches.

Comment: You can pipe into findstr.